# Does strong positivity of T implies strong positivity of T*

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space with a positive self dual cone $K$. Then a bounded operator $T$ is called

- positive if $T(K) \subseteq K$
- Strongly positive if $T\left(\mathrm{int}\left(K\right)\right) \subseteq K \setminus \{0\} $.

I verified that if $K$ is self-dual, i.e. $K^{*}=K$, then $T$ is positive implies $T^{*}$ is positive. I don't know whether such implication is true for strong positivity.  Please help me tho check whether the following holds or not:

> "If $K$ is a self dual cone, then $T$ is strongly positive implies $T^{*}$ is strongly positive."

I was just able to prove that $T^{*}x\neq 0$ for $x\in \mathrm{int}(K)$, but not able to proceed further.

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know why strong positivity implies positivity?  Because if you know that $T$ is positive, then you already know $T^*$ is positive, hence $T^*(\mathrm{int}(K))\subseteq T^*(K)\subseteq K$, so with your last line, you would be done.

Comment: Thank you!Actually I used the result that $int(K)=\{x\in X :\langle x,y \rangle > 0 \textit{for all}  y\in K\setminus\{0\}\}$ to prove the last line in the question. Just now I realized that I don't know whether this result is true for infinite dimensional spaces. Can anyone please clarify this or can anyone give an alternate proof of the last line.